# To set up BitTorrent Sync with Buffalo NAS Linkstation

Tags: linux, nas, bittorrent-sync, buffalo-nas

I have been reading this [page](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/18058-problem-with-buffalo-linkstation-duo-ls-wxl-100-cpu/?hl=buffalo) about setting up Bittorrent Sync embedded into the Buffalo NAS linkstation (my firmware version 1.56). 
It refers to this [page](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Category:LS-WXL#Gain_Root_Access) about Buffalo's settings. 
Here a detailed discussion about how to do [this](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Open_Stock_Firmware_LS-VL).

I run

```
java -jar acp_commander.jar -t 192.168.0.100 -ip 192.168.0.100 -pw 123456
```

where I have verified that the password is correct. 
I get

```
Using random connID value = C1121AFB1BD1
Using target:   192.168.0.100/192.168.0.100
Starting authentication procedure...
Sending Discover packet...  
Found:  LS-WSXL1E7 (/192.168.0.100)     LS-WSXL(KINMEI) (ID=00111)  mac: 00:24:A1:71:C1:E1  Firmware=  1.560    Key=1D11D1E1
Trying to authenticate EnOneCmd...  ACP_STATE_OK
Trying to authenticate with admin password...   ACP_STATE_OK
Changeing IP:   ACP_STATE_FAILURE
Please note, that the current support for the change of the IP is currently very rudimentary.
The IP has been set to the given, fixed IP, however DNS and gateway have not been set. Use the WebGUI to make appropriate settings.
```

and another time, I get

```
Using random connID value = C1121AFB1BD1
Using target:   192.168.0.100/192.168.0.100
Starting authentication procedure...
Sending Discover packet...  
Found:  LS-WSXL1E7 (/192.168.0.100)     LS-WSXL(KINMEI) (ID=00111)  mac: 00:24:A1:71:C1:E1  Firmware=  1.560    Key=1D11D1E1
Trying to authenticate EnOneCmd...  ACP_STATE_OK
Trying to authenticate with admin password...   ACP_STATE_OK
A SocketTimeoutException usually indicates bad firewall settings.
Check especially for *UDP* port 22936 and make sure that the connection to your LS is working.
ERROR: Exception: SocketTimeoutException (Receive timed out) [ACP Send/Receive (Packet:8030 = ACP_Change_IP)]
```

I go to my Buffalo NAS settings and see that I have these settings in WebAccess

[image]

I have these Advanced firewall settings in my router D-link DIR-645

[image]

where UPnP IGD enabled as required in the advices about setting up BT sync. 
Some details of my router

- nothing in *32 -- IPV6 FIREWALL RULES*
- nothing in *IPV6 ROUTING*
- nothing in *PORT FORWARDING*

How can you solve the error messages in installing BT Sync for Buffalo NAS linkstation?

### Some NASes with work with BitTorrent Sync 2015

- [How a Motion Designer Integrates BitTorrent Sync with his Workflow for Backup and Accessibility](http://blog.getsync.com/2015/07/29/how-a-motion-designer-integrates-bittorrent-sync-with-his-workflow-for-backup-and-accessibility/) where he is using *WD MyCloud EX2* answered [here](https://twitter.com/imcalledandy/status/628181662610911232)

How to set up BitTorrent Sync with Buffalo NAS Linkstation?

Answer (score 2):

> The IP has been set to the given, fixed IP, however DNS and gateway have not been set. Use the WebGUI to make appropriate settings.

Apparently, your network configuration is incomplete.

Have you tried setting these from your WebGUI, exactly as suggested by the above error message?

You should be able to find your own gateway easily enough, but at any rate it is typically either 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.254. As for the DNS, you can use Google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) and they will work.